# Replace function in javascript on someone else's website

Tags: javascript

I want to replace some code in a function. The function looks like this:

```
function test (d) {
   for(var k in d) {
     if(d[k].icon != undefined) {
        d[k].icon = path + d[k].icon;
     }
   } 
}
```

I want replace this function because I cannot set image with full url. So I need to remove `path` from this function. This function is not mine, but on a website. Is it possible?

Comment: No, if this is not your own function - it is not possible to replace the code for other people. It might be possible to replace it on your own computer if you have a proper browser extension installed.

Comment: Improved English. Pointed out that the code isn't on the asker's website.

Comment: I suggest you look into userscript plugins such as GreaseMonkey / TamperMonkey / ViolentMonkey

Comment: In Javascript, if it's in-scope, you can redefine the function and your redefinition can remove the part you don't want.

Comment: Can you help me redefine this?